Hiring HR unresponsive after committing to offer letter
I applied for a job and was in touch with HR since a now a month and 15 days regarding onboarding. It is offshore so fair bit of back and forth, where we set up salary, relocation and everything . They kept me updated regularly on the status. At time X, they committed to an offer letter in the next week. It did not arrive, and the week after, they were on vacation.
During this week and week before, I did send 2-3 follow ups to HR (cc'ing the people they mentioned to contact in their absence) and each of them was not answered. I reached out to the hiring manager who is on vacation himself but will check when he is back.
Week0- committing to offer in week1, week2- OOO, right now we are in week 3.
At this point I am a bit frustrated at lack of response since I'm moving around a fair bit doing formalities for the move. I'm thinking if an offer can ever be pulled this way. It's a big firm so I don't expect this.
I want to understand who to contact for further inquiry and what should be the next step. In particular is it a good idea to keep emailing them until they respond? If I am being a bit impatient also do let me know.
Thank you!
Update: Finally the HR got on call and said the COO needs to discuss something with the hiring manager first which is why it is on hold. They promised to update the next day but picked up 0 calls and did not respond to 2 email follow ups either since.

what countries are involved here? This would be fairly normal for some countries but a real flag in others.

@Hilmar for sake not revealing too much it would help if you could list down that. Both are in Asia though.

@user121416 - So you should specify we are talking about Asia in your question instead of a comment.


I reached out to the hiring manager who is on vacation himself but will check when he is back.

Do you know when he would be back ? Can you ask HR this question ?
Sometimes, the manager may have a 3 or 4 week long vacation if they go back to their own country to visit their relatives or parents.
When the manager returns from the vacation, he will reply to you most likely.

You can call HR directly because it may be faster and more direct. Also, email them again if you wish. Try to contact the recruiters via their LinkedIn pages, etc...
There is no guarantee that they will reply you though.
So, the most important thing you can do is to make sure that you keep looking and applying for jobs at many other companies.

Back next week, I can ask HR but they are not answering in the first place whether or not the process is going as agreed. Is messaging them on other apps professional?

This might be a red flag.  Although this is a large company, you won't have any reckoning of how things really work inside until you are hired.  If they're being this sloppy with their hiring, what else might they be sloppy with?
I think you've done as much as you should right now.  Doing much more, after you've contacted all these people, is a little desperate and might prompt someone to backtrack on your salary requirements or other things on the table.  You'll start to look as if you don't have any other options for employment, which is NOT a good position to be in.
Move on, and keep looking for other opportunities.  Maybe something will materialize with this job.  If you are contacted, you should mention that the long delay has caused you some inconvenience.  If the person you speak to is defensive or deflects, TREAD CAREFULLY, as this is a sign of more similar behavior to come.

I actually have mentioned a competing offer that I may take in case the delay is quite a lot, and I know the hiring manager well so it's personal. It's just that the specific role here is superlative and I don't want to miss.

I actually laughed out loud at "superlative".  Sorry.  It's just my belief that the same distance you raise a job opportunity (or people) up on a pedestal above you is the same distance that either can come crashing down again.  Don't worship a workplace.  Make your $$$ and go home to your loved ones!  My two cents.

Thanks man! This certainly helped
